# Nginx - serving assets from user directories

Tags: nginx

I have 2 issues.

I don't want to require .html file extension for html files

`/index => /index.html`

I want to serve from user directories

`/~username serves from /home/username/www/`

I previously used try_files to achieve (1), and I am user the nginx UserDir suggestion:

```
location ~ /^/~(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
   alias /home/$1/www$2;
   index index.html index.htm;
   autoindex on;
}
```

The above works for user directories but still requires the .html ext to be used.
I know there is a known bug preventing alias and try_files from working well together.

Thoughts? Sorry if this has been answered before couldn't find a working solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always replace `alias` with `root`

```
location ~ /^/~([^/]+)(/.*)?$ {
  root /home/$1/www;
  autoindex on;
  try_files $2 $2/ $2.html;
}
```

PS: move the `index` to the server scope instead of location

Comment: thanks. that worked. feels dirty using root again but until the alias and try_files bug is fixed guess this is the only way. thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit old, but as I've been hit by the same problem recently, here is my answer. Thanks to http://marc.info/?l=nginx&m=124533515814122&w=2 I've found that a better answer would be:

```
location ~ /^/~(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
  alias /home/$1/www$2;
  index index.html index.htm;
  autoindex on;
  try_files "" .html / =404; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the `.html` extention to the location regex and the alias:

```
location ~ /^/~(.+?)(/.*)?.html$ {
    alias /home/$1/www$2.html
```

Note that in this configuration, ONLY html files can be served. You can add another location to support other file extentions.

Comment: For extra safety escape the dot to the left of `html` in the regex of the location specifier. That is specify location as `/^/~(.+?)(/.*)?\.html$`